# Aspire E5574 No Bootable Device

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hardware-failure

When I turn it on it says no bootable device.  Running Windows 10. I tried reconnecting the HDD incase it was jarred loose. The boot order and UEFI boot mode stuff is all legit and checks out. But still no bootable device.
Aa 
If the HDD was jarred loose while the computer was on. Would it have corrupted my HDD and now everything I have on there is gone?  Or what's the deal with this?

Mainly I'd like to know if it's still useable and if my files are still on it, and do I have to replace the HDD? Could this problem just happen out of the blue even if the HDD was never jarred loose?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean that the hard drive is a total loss. It could be just a boot problem. The first step is to see if the drive is still operational. A couple of ways to do this: 1) Remove the drive and use a USB adapter or enclosure to connect it as an external drive on another computer. Check it there to see if it's working and you can see the directories and files on it.  2) Burn a Linux distro to a DVD or flash drive on another computer. Boot into a live session on you computer. See if the hard drive is detected and still has its contents.  The results will define the next step.

Comment: As an interim guess, the disk probabaly is otherwise in good condition, but has lost the boot connection route, and needs a bootable install DVD/USB-stick for booting and from there getting into the boot correction procedure ...

Comment: How can a hard drive just randomly lose it's boot connection?  And i have an external unit to plug the acer hdd into but can I use the hdd-less acer to check the files? Or will it still tell me no bootable device even when connected via external unit

Comment: FYI I know close to zero about computers so please excuse my lack of knowledge lol

Comment: Until you boot an operating system, your laptop is a doorstop.  You can boot from a hard drive, flash drive, or DVD.  Your hard drive isn't booting so if you want to test anything on the laptop, you will need something else.  That's why I suggested burning a Linux distro to a DVD on another machine.  They will boot into a "live session" by loading everything into memory and running from there.  Once in a live session, you can use the Linux tools to see if your hard drive is still intact.  Using an adapter or enclosure to connect the Acer drive via USB will require another PC.  (cont'd)

Comment: Assuming the boot problem lies with the drive, and not something like a bad internal SATA cable, whatever is preventing booting now will also prevent booting when connected via USB.  Boot up another computer, then connect the Acer drive via USB.  If the drive is recognized and you can see its contents, that means the issue is limited to a boot problem.  In that case, there are several possible causes.  There are too many possibilities to exhaustively cover them all, so narrow it down and then we can take it the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is a possible answer what you can try. It should resolve your problem
Follow the below steps :

1. Press F2 the moment your laptop starts.
2. Now you would be welcomed by a known BIOS menu.
3. Go to Boot menu and change boot option from UEFI to Legacy.
4. Press F10 and then Enter.
5. Now reboot your system and you should see the windows icon.